# Two video cards on one motherboard

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, pci-express

I recently purchased a new HP Pavilion p6-2265eo. It was then that I realised that it has only one DVI and one HDMI output.. I will connect my TV with the HDMI. so I am letft with only one DVI output.

I need to have two monitors. Should I purchase a new video card and install it?
My knowledge is limited. The specifications of my comp says that there is 1 x PCI-E x16, 3 x PCI-E x1.

1. I suppose that the video card already present in my purchase is connected on the PCI-E x16. Am I right? I don't want to open my desktop right now and check it for myself as it can void the warranty. So I need an experienced person to tell me that.
2. I have an old Nvidia GeForce 7200 GT. Is it possible for me to connect it to my left over PCI-E x1? I searched for PCI-E x1 on the net and as far as I can understand the slot is too small for my old Nvidia GeForce 7200 GT graphic card.

What are the options?

Comment: Your PCI-e x1 slot may be open-ended. This means that you can fit a larger card such as an x4. Some of the lanes will not be connected, but that is OK in open-ended slots. The card will just use the x1 part. This is a bit slower, so 3D games won't work on the second monitor.

Answer (score 1):

According to [specs](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c03411817&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=135&contentType=SupportFAQ&prodSeriesId=5258508&prodTypeId=12454) of your PC the only possible option is to change to a graphics card to one that support three ports output.

Answer (score 1):

All info found on the HP Official Spec page for this computer:

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c03411817&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=135&contentType=SupportFAQ&prodSeriesId=5258508&prodTypeId=12454

1. Yes, the video card is inserted into the PCI-E x 16 slot.
2. According to the HP Spec page for your computer,the motherboard does not have a AGP slot.  From my basic search on a 7200GT video card, it is an AGP video card, so the answer is 'No! You cannot add this card to your new computer.'
3. Your remaining options are to find a video card that has a PCI-E x 1 connector, find a video card that supports multiple monitors (as suggested by Petr), or find a splitter that can split the video signal (not sure if this would work for whatever it is you want to do).

Comment: NVidia's site doesn't list a GT version. The closest is a [7200GS](http://www.nvidia.com/page/geforce_7200.html), which _is_ PCI-e

Answer (score 0):

I would look at something like this if you don't want to void the warranty or open the case. It's just USB and we use them at work with good success. Can add another if you want even more monitors.

http://www.evga.com/uvplus/